# Using make_iterator_range with std::string

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I'd like to do a `to_upper()` call on a substring, and thus pass in a range. I don't understand why I cannot construct a range on a `string`, but can on a `vector` in the same way.

Using Xcode 6.3.2 with compiler option `-std=c++11` and Boost 1.58

```
void string_test() {
    std::string my_str = "Hello, world, it's a wonderful day";    
    std::vector<int> x  = {1,2,3,4,5,6,6,8,9,10};
    const auto rng = boost::make_iterator_range(x.begin(),x.end()-5);
    const auto rng2 = boost::make_iterator_range(my_str.begin(),my_str.begin()+10);
    // How do I get to_upper_copy to accept the range returned above
    std::cout << boost::to_upper_copy(rng2) << std::endl;

}
```

I get an error in Xcode:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:215:11: No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<char *>'
```

Comment: `I cannot construct a range on a string` What's stopping you? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error doesn't have anything to do with creating an `iterator_range` from `string`; if you comment out the call to `to_upper_copy`, your code will compile. Similarly, if you swap `string` with `vector<char>` (or even `vector<int>`), the call to `to_upper_copy` will again fail to compile with similar errors.

Clearly, the culprit is [`to_upper_copy`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.case_conv_hpp), and looking at the signature of the function template tells us why.

```
template<typename SequenceT> 
SequenceT to_upper_copy(const SequenceT &, 
                        const std::locale & = std::locale());
```

You cannot pass in a pair of `string::iterator`s, which is what your `make_iterator_range` call essentially returns , as `SequenceT` because there would be no easy way for the algorithm to construct a new `SequenceT` given a pair of iterators. This is described in the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/string_algo/design.html#string_algo.string) as well:

> In addition some algorithms have additional requirements on the string-type. Particularly, it is required that an algorithm can create a new string of the given type. In this case, it is required that the type satisfies the sequence **(Std §23.1.1)** requirements.
>
> In the reference and also in the code, requirement on the string type is designated by the name of template argument. `RangeT` means that the basic range requirements must hold. **`SequenceT` designates extended sequence requirements**.

Note that the section referred to above is from the C++03 standard. In C++11 and later documents, the relevant section is *§23.2.3 [sequence.reqmts]*.

So an `iterator_range` does not satisfy the requirements of `SequenceT`. If you pass `my_str` instead to `to_upper_copy` your code does compile. But if you want to only convert a sub-string, then you'll need to create a `string` containing that, and then call `to_upper`.

```
std::cout << boost::to_upper_copy(my_str) << std::endl; // works, but not a sub-string

std::string substr(rng2.begin(), rng2.end());
boost::to_upper(substr);
std::cout << substr << std::endl;
```

---

You can also avoid constructing the intermediate sub-string by using the `to_upper_copy` overload that takes an output iterator argument.

```
std::string result;
result.reserve(rng2.size());
boost::to_upper_copy(std::back_inserter(result), rng2);
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54e99d59a347a8c5)

Comment: I wrote my answer at the same time which came to the same conclusion; though I solved in a different way by converting to a vector<char>. However that has lead to separate SO question

Comment: @Ronnie I just thought of an alternate implementation that avoids constructing the sub-string. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realised after @Praetorian's answer that you can remove the smaller string allocation or vector copy completely by using the overloaded to_upper_copy() passing in the output iterator.

```
void string_algo() {
    const std::string my_str = "Hello, world, it's a wonderful day";
    const auto rng2 = boost::make_iterator_range(my_str.begin(),my_str.begin()+10);
    boost::to_upper_copy(rng2.begin(),rng2);
    std::cout << rng2 << std::endl;
}
```